# Difference between "Industrial" and "Industrialized world"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-choice

How do these phrases differ?

> Industrialized world
>
> Industrial world

Do both the phrases give the same meaning, or are they different?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: Different.

Long Answer: It's the difference between a "world that has been industrialized" and "the world of industry."

Without making political or social commentary of any kind, an "industrialized world" typically refers to

> [a more developed country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developed_country).

whereas the "industrial world" is more like

> all the companies that make up "industry," such as, factories, manufacturing and manufacturers, etc.